# Show that $\pi =3\arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}) + 3\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

> Question:
>
> Show that, $$\pi =3\arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}) +
>  3\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) ~~~~~~ (*)$$

*My proof method for this question has received mixed responses. Some people say it's fine, others say that it is a verification, instead of a proof.*

Proof: $$\pi =3\arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}) + 3\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})\iff \frac{\pi}{3} = \arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}) + \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}) 
$$$$\iff \frac{\pi}{3} = \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5})+\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$$

As $\arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}})=\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5})$

The plan now is to apply the tangent function to both sides, and show that LHS=RHS using the tangent addition formula to expand it out.

I.e. $$\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \tan\bigg(\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5})+\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\bigg)$$

$$\iff \sqrt{3} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}$$

and the RHS will reduce down to $\sqrt{3}$. Hence LHS=RHS.

Some things that I've noticed about this method of proof:

- It could be used to (incorrectly) prove that $$\frac{\pi}{3}+\pi = \arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}) + \arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$$

So because this method of proof can be used to prove things true, that are obviously false, that means it can't be used?

- Instead of proving (*), wouldn't this method of proof actually prove that? $$\arccos(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}})+\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})=\frac{\pi}{3} + \pi k$$

for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ which we must find. In this case being when $k=0$.

Comment: @JanEerland Very sorry. I should've triple-checked before submitting this question. I've fixed it now

Comment: "It could be used to (incorrectly) prove that ..." : **No**, it couldn't.  The two angles in question are both in the first quadrant, so their sum can't be in the 3rd quadrant.  If $x > 0$, then Arctan$(x)$ is in the 1st quadrant.  Ditto for Arccos$(x)$.

Comment: The question that you posted asked that you **verify** the sum of two angles, rather than **derive** the sum of two angles.  Therefore, it is not appropriate to criticize your analysis for verifying rather than deriving the sum of the two angles.

Comment: @user2661923 Doesn't "Show that" $\implies$ "Prove that" $\implies$ derive?

Comment: Show that $A + B = C$ is distinct from derive the (**unknown**) sum $A + B$.  Verifying that $A + B = C$ is the same as proving that $A + B = C$, but is different from deriving the sum of $A + B$.

Comment: [I'd say](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/42106/difference-between-show-and-prove/42109#comment9144820_42109) that "verify that" ⟹ "show that" ⟺ "prove that" ⟸ "derive". The only gap in your proof is that the implicit implication $$\frac\pi3=\arctan(\frac{\sqrt3}5)+\arctan(\frac{\sqrt3}2)⟹\tan(\frac\pi3)=\tan\bigg(\arctan(\frac{\sqrt3}5)+\arctan(\frac{\sqrt3}2\bigg)$$ needs to be expanded into an equivalence instead (i.e., you need to additionally assert and justify that the reverse direction is also true, by showing that $\arctan(\frac{\sqrt3}5)+\arctan(\frac{\sqrt3}2)<\frac\pi2).$

Comment: Ohh. @ryang I understand. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using complex numbers:
$$
\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5})+\arctan(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})
= \arg((5+\sqrt{3}i)(2+\sqrt{3}i))
= \arg(7+7\sqrt{3}i)
= \arctan(\sqrt{3})
$$

Answer (score 2):

To show:

$$\text{arctan}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}\right) ~+~ \text{arctan}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) ~~<~~ \frac{\pi}{2}.$$

In fact this conclusion is immediate by the following analysis.

Let $~\displaystyle \theta ~~=~~ \text{arctan}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5}\right) ~+~ \text{arctan}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right).$

Then,

$$\tan(\theta) = 
\frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{1 - \left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right]}. \tag1 $$

In (1) above, the numerator is clearly positive.

Further, since $~\displaystyle \left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{5} \times \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right] = \frac{9}{10} < 1$,

the denominator in (1) above is also clearly positive.

Therefore, since $\tan(\theta) > 0$, either $\theta$ is in the 1st quadrant, or $\theta$ is in the 3rd quadrant.

However, by the definition of the arctan function, $\theta$ is the sum of two angles, each of which are between $(0)$ and $(\pi/2)$.  Therefore, $\theta$ can not be in the 3rd quadrant.  Therefore, $\theta$ must be in the first quadrant.

---

**Edit**
Thanks to ryang for pointing out a couple of analytical gaps that need to be filled:

- By definition, $\text{arccos}\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{28}}\right)$ is in the 1st quadrant.  Similarly $\text{arctan}\left(\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ is also in the 1st quadrant.  Therefore, $\theta$ is in fact the sum of $2$ angles, each of which are in the first quadrant.
- In general $\tan(\theta) = \tan(\pi/3)$ does not imply that $\theta = (\pi/3)$.  However, if you add the constraint that $\theta$ is in the 1st quadrant, then the implication holds.  Since I deduced that $\theta$ is in the 1st quadrant, the analysis holds.

Comment: No worries; elaborating on my original comment: you started your proof with the given statement (*) and, via a sequence of _equivalences_, arrived at the conclusion that $\sqrt3=\sqrt3.$ (This is a valid proof technique, in spite of some of the earlier comments claiming otherwise.) Except that there was _one_ missing equivalence: that step from $\frac{\pi}{3} = \theta$ to $\tan(\frac{\pi}{3}) = \tan \theta$ was merely (implicitly) an implication (⟹) instead of an equivalence (⟺) (after all, applying a trig function on an eqn....

Comment: ....is not generally a reversible procedure, e.g. $\tan x=\tan y\kern.6em\not\kern-.6em\implies x=y$ even though the converse is true); fortunately we observe that $θ$ happens to be acute, and therefore that implication is indeed reversible after all; this observation (even if you think it is immediate) ought to be specified or briefly explained, just like the other proof steps.

Comment: Are you now asking whether your self-Answer _validly_ plugs your originally-suggested proof? Yes—that's why I upvoted it (as well as lhf's complex analysis).

Comment: @ryang See the end of my edited answer.

Comment: Hey, I'm making a link to this post, and in the process, just realised that you are not the OP. (I'd thought that it was the OP plugging up their own proof.)

Answer (score 1):

You have$$3\arccos\left(\frac5{\sqrt{28}}\right)\in[0,3],$$since $\frac{\sqrt3}2<\frac5{\sqrt{28}}<1$, and therefore$$3>3\frac\pi6>3\arccos\left(\frac5{\sqrt{28}}\right)>0.$$You also have$$0\leqslant3\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)<3\arctan\left(\sqrt3\right)=\pi,$$and therefore$$\arccos\left(\frac5{\sqrt{28}}\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt3\right)\in\left[0,\frac\pi3+1\right].$$What you did shows that$$\tan\left(\arccos\left(\frac5{\sqrt{28}}\right)+\arctan\left(\sqrt3\right)\right)=\tan\left(\frac\pi3\right).$$But the only number in $\left[0,\frac\pi3+1\right]$ whose tangent is $\tan\left(\frac\pi3\right)$ is $\frac\pi3$. So, your proof is indeed correct.

Comment: It is true that $\arccos(5/\sqrt{28})$ lies between $0$ and $1$, but you need to justify this. If, for instance, you can prove that $5/\sqrt{28}>\sqrt3/2$, then you can render $\arccos(5/\sqrt{28})<\pi/6<1$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I've edited my answer. Thank you.